# Matching criteria to display onto another sheet in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need a truck list to be sorted out by departments, here is how the truck list is laid out:
[Truck List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhnpY.png)

The list needs to be sorted out by departments in the skus tab, which looks like this:
[Sku list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guOGH.png)

And sorted by department on the Floor list tab with all the information from the truck tab, but just the items in each department in the list its categorized under:
[Floor list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVYOs.png)

I've tried using `VLOOKUP` and MATCH but all I got was cells that just say #VALUE, and it displayed more items than what should have been displayed (i.e. if there we only 5 matches, it would display the total length of the sheet with cells saying #VALUE)

Comment: In your first image, are the skus in each column? If so you can query this data to reformat it into a single list. As for the second image, you're trying to pull these descriptions into the first list? it's unclear how you have things structured and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes the sku's are in each column/row, those sku's belong to a specific department. The second list, is a truck list of every sku on the truck. I want to break the truck list down by department, which unfortunalty doesn't have the department on the truck list, so the only way I can think of is create a sku list for each department, then somehow have those sku's pulled into a seperate list by department. I hope that clarifies things..

Comment: so is there a separate tab for the skus for each department? you need to give more context on how things are structured for the community to offer any guidance. I'd still recommend querying the data so it's in one table and add the labels then for which department they're for, but this is without knowing what info is available or how it's structured.